# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar tres gráficas en un plot donde hay varias gráficas?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, slider

Cordial saludo compañeros, tengo algunos inconvenientes con el siguiente código, sucede que en la primera gráfica necesito mostrar tres funciones seno desfasadas pero no se como añadirlas al código pues siempre me da error.

otro detalle es que las gráficas aparecen muy juntas, me gustaría separarlas mas para que las etiquetas no se estorben entre ellas, muchas gracias por su ayuda. la imagen muestra las dos gráficas que están muy pegadas entre ellas, por lo que me gustaría separarlas un poco mas, subir la gráfica de la curva seno, y pues el aspecto mas importante es que deben mostrarse 3 ondas en la primera gráfica pero me da error cuando intento return en la función y graficar, realmente no se como mostrarlas, un saludo.

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

#Funcion que define la accion de los controles deslizantes
def sliders_on_changed(val):
    line1.set_ydata(FuncionTorque(r2_slider.val, AMP_slider.val))
    line2.set_ydata(FuncionSeno(AMP_slider.val))
    fig1.canvas.draw_idle()

#funcion de la tension trifasica.
def FuncionSeno(A):

    x = np.arange(0.0, 2*np.pi, 0.0001)
    V1 = A*np.sin(x)
    #V2 = A*np.sin(x+(120*np.pi)/180)
    #V3 = A*np.sin(x+(240*np.pi)/180)
    return V1

#funcion para calcular el torque de la maquina.
def FuncionTorque(r2, AMP):

    #valores requeridos del programa

    r1 = 0.641 #resistencia del estator.
    x1 = 1.106 #reactancia del estator.
    x2 = 0.464 #reactancia del rotor.
    xm = 26.3 #reactancia del circuito tanque.

    voltaje_fase = AMP/math.sqrt(3)
    n_sincronismo_rad = 188.5

    #Calcuamos el voltaje e impedancia de Thevenin.

    vth = voltaje_fase * (xm /math.sqrt(r1**2 + (x1 + xm)**2))

    zth = ((xm*1j)*(r1 + x1*1j)) / (r1 + (x1 + xm)*1j)
    rth = zth.real
    xth = zth.imag

    #Calculamos la caracteristica par vs velocidad.
    torque = ((3*vth**2*r2)/s) / (n_sincronismo_rad*((rth + (r2)/s)**2 + (xth + x2)**2))
    return torque

#Codigo general

axis_color = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
fig1 = plt.figure("CURVA PAR VS VELOCIDAD")

ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(224)
plt.title("Curva Par vs Velocidad")
plt.xlabel("Velocidad sincrona - RPM", fontsize = 7)
plt.ylabel("Torque inducido - N.M", fontsize = 7)
plt.grid(True)

ax2 = fig1.add_subplot(222)
plt.title("Onda trifasica de la tension")
plt.xlabel("Variacion en el tiempo - S", fontsize = 7)
plt.ylabel("Tension de entrada - V", fontsize = 7)
plt.grid(True)

#valores iniciales del programa.
A = 460
r2 = 0.332
s = np.arange(0.001,1,0.001)
n_sincronismo = 1800
nm = (1 - s)*n_sincronismo
x = np.arange(0.0, 2*np.pi, 0.0001)

#Ajuste del espacio de ubicacion de las graficas.
fig1.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, bottom=0.25)

#Creacion de la grafica a modificar
[line1] = ax1.plot(nm, FuncionTorque(r2,A), linewidth= 1, color='r')
[line2] = ax2.plot(x, FuncionSeno(A), linewidth = 1)

#controles deslizantes

#Definimos el control deslizante para la resistencia rotorica
r2_slider_ax1  = fig1.add_axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.55, 0.03], facecolor= axis_color)
r2_slider = Slider(r2_slider_ax1, 'R2', 0.001, 1.5, valinit= r2)

#Definimos el control deslizante para la amplitud de la tension
AMP_slider_ax1 = fig1.add_axes([0.25, 0.05, 0.55, 0.03], facecolor=axis_color)
AMP_slider = Slider(AMP_slider_ax1, 'AMP', 0.001, 500.0, valinit= A)

#activacion del control deslizante.
r2_slider.on_changed(sliders_on_changed)
AMP_slider.on_changed(sliders_on_changed)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Para la gráfica del seno desfasada, imagino que el desfase que quieres es el que hay en las líneas comentadas `V1` y `V2`, lo que puedes hacer es por ejemplo lo siguiente:

Añades un nuevo parametro a la función que indique el desfase que quieres:

```
def FuncionSeno(A, desfase):
    x = np.arange(0.0, 2 * np.pi, 0.0001)
    V = A * np.sin(x + (desfase * np.pi) / 180)
    return V
```

En la parte en la que creas las gráficas añades las siguientes líneas:

```
# Creacion de la grafica a modificar
[line1] = ax1.plot(nm, FuncionTorque(r2, A), linewidth=1, color='r')
[line2] = ax2.plot(x, FuncionSeno(A, 0), linewidth=1)
[line3] = ax2.plot(x, FuncionSeno(A, 120), linewidth=1)
[line4] = ax2.plot(x, FuncionSeno(A, 240), linewidth=1)
```

Con esto ya habrías solucionado la parte de añadir las tres funciones del seno.

Para la parte del solapamiento entre gráficas puedes pasarle un parámetro más a `subplots_adjust()`. Al pasarle `hspace` le indicas el espacio vertical que quieres dejar entre gráficas (he puesto 1, prueba cambiandolo). Por lo que modificando la línea así:

```
# Ajuste del espacio de ubicacion de las graficas.
fig1.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, bottom=0.25, hspace=1)
```

Conseguirías dejar las gráficas ya listas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por último, no sé si tenías pensado añadir más gráficas, porque tal y como lo tienes ahora está distribuido para tener 4 (por eso las dos que has hecho te salen tan a la derecha).

Si no vas a añadir más, cambia estas líneas:

```
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(212)
ax2 = fig1.add_subplot(211)
```

El primer numero (2) son las filas, el segundo (1) las columnas y el tercero (1 y 2) el índice. Así te saldrá como lo tenías pero centrado, y si cambias el margen izquierdo para que no salga cortado ya lo tendrás del todo:

```
fig1.subplots_adjust(left=0.2, bottom=0.25, hspace=1)
```

**Actualización**

Para hacer que los Sliders sigan funcionando, lo más rápido sería poner estas líneas en la función `sliders_on_changed`, así haces que las tres funciones se actualicen:

```
line2.set_ydata(FuncionSeno(AMP_slider.val, 0))
line3.set_ydata(FuncionSeno(AMP_slider.val, 120))
line4.set_ydata(FuncionSeno(AMP_slider.val, 240))
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, perfecta tu explicación. Ya había intentado algo parecido pero me saltaba error cuando modificaba el parámetro amp, lo que sucede es que tengo un control deslizante y cuando modifico amp sale 
    TypeError: FuncionSeno() missing 1 required positional argument: 'desfase'

Comment: ¿que puedo hacer ahi?